# import Xml file into java application

Tags: java, swing, file-io

i want to import an XML file into my Java application . 
this is the function :

```
static void lireFichier(String fichier) throws Exception
{
    SAXBuilder sxb = new SAXBuilder();
    document = sxb.build(new File(fichier));
    racine = document.getRootElement();
}
```

and this is how i call it

```
lireFichier("exemple.xml");
```

This is part of a Swing application. I want the user to be able to specify the XML file to open. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something like lireFichier("/path/to/your/file/exemple.xml") ?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Swing, JDOM, or XML and all to do with basic file I&O. Tags edited.

Comment: no , because the file's name could be changed . in fact my application  takes as argument the XML file and then display a dynamic graph associeted to th the file ! so i want to import any xml file with any name .

Comment: If the program takes the file name as argument, it's up to the user of the program to pass the appropriate file name (and path). Why should you care?

Comment: because i am the one who must impliment the code witch enable the user to surf into directories and select the XMLfile

Comment: Then use a Swing solution of a JFileChooser and use the full file name/path obtained from the selected file.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I edited the OP with the real question from these comments. You might want to add your suggestion as an answer now...or I could just steal it as my own answer...

Comment: @Code: please go ahead and post this as an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Doh! MadProgrammer beat me to it ;-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a basic concept that could have been easily solved with minimal research.

You need to spend some time reading through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) in particular.

I'd also recommend a crash course on the [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API as well...

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setDialogTitle("Open stuff");
fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml") || f.isDirectory();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "XML Document (*.xml)";
    }
});

switch (fc.showOpenDialog(null)) {
    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        lireFichier(file.getPath()); 
        break;
}
```

Comment: And you hope that it is a small xml file as typically you do not want the reading/processing of files (not sure what the `lireFichier` method exactly does but it looks like some XML parsing as well) on the EDT

Comment: yes i want to parse the XML file and extract information to draw a causal graph from XML tags . so the XML file will be the input and the dynamic garph is the output of my application

Comment: Rad1 Just beware that loading and parsing the XML file can be time consuming processing. Robin is just reminding us that doing so will block the UI event queue (the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT)), which would make your application look like its hung

Answer (score 1):

**-** Its simple, just pass the `path` of the `File` as String, where your `XML` file is located.

**eg:**

`File f = new File("d:\\Myfolder\\vivek.xml");`

**-** You can always also use the following easy to use `APIs` to parse the XML.

- `JAXP & JAXB`
- `CASTOR`

Comment: jaxb and castor only make sense if the xml has a pre-defined structure.